# How a complex root $\eta$ of $x^2 + x + A$ affects the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\eta]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

While reading a statement in P. Pollack's *Not Always Buried Deep: A Second Course in Elementary Number Theory* I came across a statement that seemed obvious and I am wondering if I am oversimplifying and perhaps missing something.

The statement reads

> Let $A \geq 2$ be an integer, and fix a complex root $\eta$ of $x^2 + x + A$, so that (for an appropriate choice of the square root) $\eta = (-1 + \sqrt{D})/2$. Since $\eta^2 = -\eta - A$, it follows that $$\mathbb{Z}[\eta] = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\eta = \{ x + y\eta : x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$$

While I certainly agree that $\eta^2 = - \eta - A$, I am not sure why it follows that $\mathbb{Z}[\eta] = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\eta = \{ x + y\eta : x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. I was under the assumption that $\mathbb{Z}[\eta]$ denoted the set $\{ x + y\eta : x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ by definition regardless of the aforementioned relationship satisfied by $\eta$.

Comment: In fact, $\Bbb Z[\eta]$ denotes all polynomial expressions in $\eta$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$ (not just linear polynomial expressions). So for example, $\pi^2\in\Bbb Z[\pi]$ and $\eta^3+3\eta^2+7\in\Bbb Z[\eta]$.

Comment: @GregMartin so really they are just trying to make it clear that you can reduce expressions, such as the one you wrote, using this relationship?

Comment: That seems to be the case Oiler. A relation like $\eta^2=1-\eta/2$ wouldn't work, but when $\eta$ is a zero of a monic quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients we always have $\Bbb{Z}[\eta]=\Bbb{Z}+\Bbb{Z}\eta$.